# php GET form action in the same php file

Tags: php, forms, post, get

i have a file 'functions.php' that includes several methods. one of these methods is displaying a GET form containing one drop down list.

```
        <form action="" method="GET">
    <select name="123_cat" class ="styled" onchange="this.form.submit();">  
   <?php foreach($subcategories['categories'] as $sc) { ?>
   <optgroup label="<?php echo $sc['name']; ?>">
    <?php foreach ($sc['subcategories'] as $ss){?>                              
             <option id = "123_cat" value="<?php echo $ss['sid']; ?>" <?php if (isset($_GET['123_cat'])) { if($ss['sid'] == $_GET['123_cat']) echo 'selected = "selected"';} else { if(in_array($ss['sid'], $the_subcategories)) echo 'selected = "selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $ss['name']; ?></option>
        <?php }?>
```

after that, i have in the same functions.php a method that throws me some categories from a json.

```
   function get_deals($subcategories = array(), $page = 0, $deals_per_page = 10, $city = "bucuresti",$format = "json")
 {
global $wpdb;   
$site_root = "https://123reduceri.ro/";
$api_root = "api/v3/";
$table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "123reduceri";
$my_data = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT * FROM $table_name ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1");
$token = $my_data->token;

 if(isset($_GET['123_city'])){
$city = $_GET['123_city']; 
  }
 else{
    $city = $my_data->city; 
 }


 if(isset($_GET['123_cat'])){
$subcategories = array($_GET['123_cat']);       
  }  
else{

$subcategories = unserialize($my_data->categories);  
}

$url = $site_root . $api_root .$city . "." . $format . "?token=" . $token .       "&white_label=1" . "&deals_per_page=" . $deals_per_page;

if($page)
{
    $url .= "&page=" . $page;
}

if(count($subcategories))
{
    $subcategories_string = implode(",", $subcategories);
    $subcategories_string = rtrim($subcategories_string, ",");
    $url .= "/".$city."?"."&subcategories=" . $subcategories_string;
}

$response = file_get_contents($url);
if($format == "json")
    return json_decode($response, TRUE);


return $response;
}
```

My problem in that after the GET form is submitted, i want to remain in the same page, and get the values based on the get_deals method. What should i have in the 'action' of the GET form? (the weird fact is that if i have a POST foveorm it works if i let the form action "" (like above))
Thank you!

Comment: To return to the same page after submitting a form leave the action attribute of the form empty `form action="" method="get"`

Comment: show the HTML code of the form.

Comment: leaving action blank apparently works. it's something with your HTML/PHP

Comment: it is weird because it worked with the form on post

Comment: Try the following in your action: <form action="<?= $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] ?>" method="get">...</form>. This should throw you to the same page you are already on. If your server doesn't support short tags (like <?= ), replace them by <?php echo ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `action = '".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'`

Answer (score -1):

You can use [jQuery and the .ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method to retrieve the values from your script.

Answer (score -1):

Just set the action to the URL of the page you are currently on (excluding get parameters)